# Better Flag Options for off topic

Tags: feature-request

So far I have flagged three good questions for being off topic on ux.stackexchange.com

I am unhappy that two are closed when really they should have been migrated to other sites.

Perhaps the 'wrong site' options should include **all** stack exchange sites so good questions can be migrated rather than closed.

Answer (score 2):

Questions that deserve to be migrated to another site are usually done so.

Some recent posts that were voted / flagged for migration that ended up being migrated are:

https://superuser.com/questions/656500/display-partial-screen-on-projector

https://superuser.com/questions/651275/eyefinity-4-monitor-setup-with-hdmi-and-dvi

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79670/power-plug-orientation-and-usability

However there are plenty of questions that get flagged for migration that do not get migrated across. [As Jeff Atwood himself says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites/82986#82986) (and often 
reiterated by many a mod!):

> **The golden rule of question migration: *never migrate crap!***

Unfortunately, many questions that don't belong on UX also don't belong anywhere on Stack Exchange either, at least in the form they were written. Primarily such questions would be one-liners, like *'why doesn't X work'* but they could equally be questions posted that have had no research whatsoever put into them and just expecting other people to do all the work for them, or they could be questions that are so unclear and badly written that they would not be comprehensible to the suggested site either.

My own personal method of migrating a question when it is flagged is to take these steps:

1. Read the question myself and see what I think of it. If it fails the golden rule (i.e. it's just crap) then I'd just close it off. However sometimes they're cut and dry that they are good questions that belong somewhere specific - presumably the poster doesn't know that site even exists.
2. Check the reputation of the person who has flagged it to see what their rep score is *on the target site*. - If the person flagging it has a large reputation there (i.e. >2000 on that site) then I assume they are good contributors to that site and know that the question would be well received, and if so I'd probably migrate over.
3. If the first two steps are inconclusive then I'd visit the moderator chat room to speak to one of the moderators of the suggested site to see if it's something they would like.

If at any stage of this process the question passes that test then I'd migrate it, otherwise it'd likely just get closed off as Off Topic and left at that.

I disagree that the 'wrong site' option should include *all* sites. Really, I think a better option would be to only include sites where the person flagging / close voting has a reputation of >2000. But that's a bit of a development overhead so I don't think that's likely to happen any time soon.

Suggesting that a question be migrated to a place it really doesn't belong could end up being a very bad experience for the question asker - for instance a very likely scenario (because it does already happen) is that they go over to StackOverflow and ask their unsuited question there because they were advised by this site to do so and then be closed-off and downvoted into oblivion because the question was unsuitable.

Comment: the questions in question ... http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/42202/is-it-legal-to-share-android-application-that-streams-movies-from-3d-party-websi ... http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45527/windows-vista-connecting-to-wireless ... both seem valid to me, but in the wrong place, maybe duplicates though, but still valid